# Create 1 Record from Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I'm trying to combine multiple rows from a single table that have a common identifier. 
So in the sample below, the `GroupIdentifier` of `1111111111111` becomes `1` record with each of the records being included as `sub Field_#`.
Some records may have `3` results that are getting combined into `1` but some may only have `1` or `2`.

Thanks

Sample Data

```
GroupIdentifier UniqueIdentifier    Direction   UserID

1111111111111   123456789       1           98685
1111111111111   123456790       2           4469
1111111111111   123456856       1           98685
1111115555555   123458765       2           5435
2222225353535   123454321       1           6565
2222225353535   123458765       3           4444
```

Expected output:

```
GroupIdentifier UniqueID_1  UniqueDirection_1   UserID_1    UniqueID_2  UniqueDirection_2   UserID_2    UniqueID_3  UniqueDirection_3   UserID_3
1111111111111   123456789   1                   98685       123456790   2                   4469        123456856   1                   98685
1111115555555   123458765   2                   5435
2222225353535   123454321   1                   6565        123458765   3                   4444
```

Comment: Is there a fixed number of rows that can occur? So is it always 1 - 2 - 3 or is this flexible?

Comment: It's almost always easier to do this type of *pivot* (which is maybe the term you're looking for to get more meaningful search results) in whatever is *consuming* this result set (i.e. another language that's more oriented towards formatting and appearance, rather than data)

Comment: The general term given to this manner of data manipulation is PIVOT. Have a read: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx - and welcome to the annoying world of PIVOTing...

Comment: One more thing to add, there is a datetime field as well and the record that comes first should be first, second second etc

Comment: CRAP! I hate Pivot tables in Excel now I have to use them in SQL as well :( :(

Comment: @MarkD: For me, the most annoying part about PIVOT in cases like this is that you can only pivot one column at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "multi-column pivot".  The easiest method is to do it manually with GROUP BY and MIN(CASE..), but it's also the least flexible if your design changes.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupIdentifier ORDER BY DateTime ) AS SortOrder FROM MyTable)
SELECT
  GroupIdentifier,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 1 THEN UniqueIdentifier END) UniqueIdentifier_1,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 1 THEN Direction        END) Direction_1,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 1 THEN UserID           END) UserID_1,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 2 THEN UniqueIdentifier END) UniqueIdentifier_2,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 2 THEN Direction        END) Direction_2,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 2 THEN UserID           END) UserID_2,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 3 THEN UniqueIdentifier END) UniqueIdentifier_3,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 3 THEN Direction        END) Direction_3,
  MIN(CASE SortOrder WHEN 3 THEN UserID           END) UserID_3
) FROM t
GROUP BY GroupIdentifier
```

Comment: You are now my most bestest friend. This worked like a champ!

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "least flexible" but from the syntax point of view I would prefer this method to, say, multiple joins.

Comment: @AndriyM, by "inflexible", I mean trivial design changes incur multiple changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. The with does the ordering to 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
with x
as
( select GroupIdentifier
  ,      UniqueIdentifier
  ,      Direction
  ,      rank() over (partition by GroupIdentifier order by Direction) index
  from   TABLE_NAME
)
select one.GroupIdentifier
,      one.UniqueIdentifier UniqueID_1
,      one.Direction UniqueDirection_1
,      one.UserID UserID_1
,      two.UniqueIdentifier UniqueID_2
,      two.Direction UniqueDirection_2
,      two.UserID UserID_2
,      three.UniqueIdentifier UniqueID_3
,      three.Direction UniqueDirection_3
,      three.UserID UserID_3
from   x one
left
outer
join   x two
on     one.GroupIdentifier = two.GroupIdentifier
and    two.index = 2
left
outer
join   x three
on     one.GroupIdentifier = three.GroupIdentifier
and    three.index = 3
where  one.index = 1
```

Comment: I tried doing something similar but couldn't get it to work. The directions aren't necessarily in order, sometimes could have 1 sometimes 1, 2,1 sometimes 2, 1, 1. It's crazy.